# Spring autosave

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring with jpa and want my entity tables to autosave but they don't.

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.project.models" });

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        em.setJpaProperties(properties);        
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:./store");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

When a new client connects it handled in this class but i want it to save them without calling the repository.save method any help?

```
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import io.horizon.model.ClientModel;
import io.horizon.net.packet.Packet;
import io.horizon.net.packet.PacketHandler;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;

@Component
public class ClientInfoPacketHandler implements PacketHandler {

    @Resource
    private Map<String, ClientModel> clients;

    @Override
    public void handlePacket(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Packet packet) {
        ClientModel clientModel = new ClientModel(packet.getString());
        switch(packet.getString()) {
        case "init":
            clientModel.setStatus(1);
            break;
        }

        //This should be saved but it doesn't unless i use the clientRepository to call the save method.
    }

}
```

ClientModel class:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
public class ClientModel {

    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private int status;

    @Id
    private String uid;

    public ClientModel() {      
    }

    public ClientModel(String uid) {        
        this.uid = uid;
    }   

}
```

Comment: And your `ClientModel` class look like?

Comment: Bad news for you: you'll have to persist it manually.

Comment: Added ClientModel class.

Comment: Calling the save method is the way to persist your entity. I'm wondering way you don't wan't to use it...

Comment: because i want to autosave is there must be some way?

Comment: Is there seriously no way i don't understand why not?